# make grid with the help of dynamically JSON array

Tags: extjs, dynamic, grid

I want to make  a grid data according to JSON response of a method means if i send JSON Array with 3 element its create column name three different name as well as 10 ,20 or more dynamically according to Array size.

Please help me or suggest me some example code.If its not feasible in extjs please suggest me to another 
frame work .
Sorry for my poor english.
Thanks
Naresh

Comment: You can do this in ExtJs you will have to build the component on the fly.   Here's a good example of how to do it: http://marcusschiesser.de/2013/12/21/dynamically-changing-the-structure-of-a-grid-in-extjs-4-2/

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want this in extjs 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Extjs 3 solution**

You can add `metaData` to the JSON response. Inside the `metaData` you can send a field-config. Listen to the [metachange](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-metachange) event and update you grid accordingly.

You can find an example here: [Dynamic Grid (ExtJs 3)](http://www.jicdesign.com/blog/web-development/extjs-dynamically-creating-grid-panel.html)

**Extjs 4+ solution**

There is a user component **Dynamic Grid** [Link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?242594-Dynamic-grid-with-dynamic-model)

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    title: 'Example of Dynamic Grid'
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [
        {
            // All what you have to set! :)
            xtype: 'dynamicGrid',
            url: '/some/url'
        }
    ]
});
```

This should do exactly what you are looking for!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am using extjs version 3.4 any suggestion for this version.

Comment: Added an extjs 3 solution!

Comment: thanks for reply .I am try this but its not work could you please give me some working code.